# Tomcat configuration in Netbeans

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I am about to try **Netbeans IDE 7.4** after I have worked with Eclipse for a long time.
I have some problems to start a **Tomcat server (7.0.32)** in the IDE, actually, I get the message : '127.0.0.1' is not recognized as an internal control or external, an executable program or batch file.

Do you have any idea, what would be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That means that the IDE cannot find the apache server you are trying to start.

You can go to the `Services` tab, and under the `servers` option, you can add a new Apache server by providing its $CATALINA_HOME dir. Then you can go in your project `properties`, and change the `run target` of your application with the new server added above.

Comment: I gave him the path to the server, it detects it (loads its classes). But still, the same problem.
I'll try with another tomcat version

Comment: also make sure you download the correct version 32-64 bit for your machine